# How do I calculate this integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate the integral $$ \int_C\frac{\sin z}{(z+i)^3}\,\mathrm{d}z, $$ where $C$ is the circle of radius $2$ around the point $0\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Can you use the residue theorem?

Comment: use Cauchy's differentiation formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: @Paul: No, I cannot.

Comment: Then you'll have a hard time in proving the integral equals $-\pi\sinh(1)$. Anyway, take a deformation of the given countour made by two loops, the first loop around $z=i$ and the second one around $z=-i$. Consider the Laurent series of the integrand function in the pointed neighbourhoods of such points.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cauchy's integral formula will help you.

$$\frac{2\pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)=\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

For your problem $n=2$, $a=-i$, $f(z)=\sin(z)$ and $f^{(n)}(z)$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f(z)$. You only need to evaluate the left hand side, as this gives you the value of the right hand side, which is the integral you want to calculate.

Note also that your singularity $z_0=-i$ is in the inside of the circle with radius $2$. If it would not be included in the circle the integral would have a value of $0$.